# Webpack: optimize multiple builds

Tags: optimization, webpack

I have a set of webpack configurations for different environments: dev, qa1, qa2, prod, etc.

The only difference between them is that they use different runtime config files used by the app. These config files store the environment-specific data, i.e.

```
{ backend_url: 'https://qa1.backend.org' }
```

When I run webpack with an array of configs, it produces an array of bundles, for each environment I need.

But this approach is not optimal, because it requires webpack to compile all the source code multiple times with almost identical output. It takes more than 20 minutes each time now for my project.

I was thinking of extracting runtime config from the bundle, in order to provide it at runtime, separately from webpack. That would allow me to create one bundle and use it across different environments. But this approach fails when I want `webpack-dev-server` to serve me the app for development use, because `webpack-dev-server` does not know how to provide me with the proper runtime config.

What am I doing wrong? How to solve the multi-environment problem, while keeping the possibility to run dev server?